# Create column from table headings using structured references

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a named table (`DATA`) in Excel. I want to create a separate table (`INFO_TABLE`) elsewhere, where one column contains the headers from the `DATA` table.

This is what I want -- the 'HEADERS' table contains a column, filled with a single formula (in the top cell of that column), spilled downwards, containing all of the header values from the first table. How can I achieve this?

[image: Desired output]

`{=DATA[#Headers]}` gives me a *row* containing the headers, but does not auto-fill (left-right) when using CSE (on Mac).
Dragging the formula down (e.g. `A2:A5`) gives only the first column name from `DATA`, shown in this screenshot:

[image: Not the desired output]

I have also tried `{=TRANSPOSE(DATA[#Headers]))}`, but this doesn't work.

(An ideal solution does not contain VBA or macros).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query:

1. Select the **Table Data**- go to **Data**- **From Table/Range**- open the **Power Query editor**:
   [image]
2. In **Power Query Editor**- under **Home** tab- select **Use Headers as First Row**
   [image]
3. Go to **Transform** tab- select **Transpose**:
   [image]
4. **Remove** null Column and **Rename** the column 1 to **Header**:
   [image]
5. Home tab- Close and Load to...:
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot enter a formula in a table that SPILLs.

But you can use this formula in the first cell of your Headers column, and drag it down as far as needed:

```
=INDEX(Data[#Headers],ROWS($1:1))
```

*As you drag down, the `ROWS` function changes automagically to return each sequential element in the `#Headers` array.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tables do not allow two things that are variations on the same idea:

1. `SPILL` formulas (presumably because of the repeating in each row of the formula for the column leading to each such formula "stepping on" those below it resulting in the spill error)
2. Using old-style arrays to do the same thing (presumably for the same reason)

You could try the following formula which does not `SPILL` or otherwise involve results that would have to display overtop the next row's results:

```
=INDEX(Table1[#Headers],1,ROW()-1)
```

Its results are a single cell of data so the RESULTS do not spill onto any other row's results. It uses the Table feature of (essentially) spilling the FORMULA so get the filled in column of results you need.

However, it only supports the number of rows that matches the number of columns in your source Table, but that presumably won't be an issue.

Either pull the Table dimensions down to have enough rows for all the columns in the source Table, then enter the formula, or enter the formula, then pull the Table dimensions down to fit the results. No extra rows, but also not too few! (Use the little marker in the Table's lower right cell's lower right corner to drag up/down (and left/right if ever needed) to size it to fit. Drag down until you have defective results, then up to the last good result. Or figure out where to drag to beforehand. Or just edit the Table's range. Lots of ways.)